# ksh script spawns unwanted child with the same name

Tags: ksh

So.. I use KSH on Solaris8 for quite long but this is the first time I got something like this:

I start a script - let's call it splitCfg. When I call `pgrep -x splitCfg` I'm finding two instances of this script - the main instance and a child of my script (output from ps):

```
root 28069 25107  0 20:22:01 pts/10   0:00 splitCfg
root  4668 28069  0 20:22:50 pts/10   0:00 splitCfg
```

As you can see - the first instance is a parent for a child. However - there is no subprocess created from the main script. When I call the ps or pgrep or ptree one more time I get:
1. no child process
or
2. a new child process

I am looking for some explanation. I believe I've search whole Internet, so it's time to ask all of you for some of your precious time :)

Is it some sort of the KSH bug (note that I'm using pretty old version from Solaris 8) or am I missing something. I understand that single script should create a single PID and leave it when it finishes.

Thanks,
Saperzasty

Comment: @saperzasty:  can you boil your script down to something you can post that shows this behaviour (you can edit it into your question)?  I suspect Norman has the answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have parenthesis in your shell script, the subshell may run in a separate Unix process, depending on what `ksh` version you have.  I think `ksh88i` (a very old version) is still shipping as the system shell on Solaris.

Comment: Norman, thanks! This is what I was looking for. I am using:
numInstances=$(/bin/pgrep -x ${CMD} | /bin/wc -l)
to get number of running instances of my script (I want only single instance at a time). CMD is a basename of ${0}. This appears only when server is heavily loaded so your suspicions are correct.

I have split this in two parts and now I get correct number.

Thank you