# Detect multiple executions of same ksh

Tags: cron, ksh

I am trying to detect if a `ksh script` is already executing in order to prevent a second instance to be executed.

The script is invoked every minute by user cronjob:

```
* * * * * /home/user/job.ksh TESTACTION &>/dev/null
```

I added a guard at the beginning of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

LOGDIR="/home/user"

processes=$(/bin/ps ux | /bin/grep -i "job.ksh TESTACTION" | /bin/grep -v grep | /bin/grep -c "\/usr\/bin\/ksh")
if (( $processes > 1 )); then
    datetime=$(/bin/date +'%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')
    /bin/echo -e "${datetime} - skipped execution for other ${processes} active process" >> "${LOGDIR}/multiple_ksh_check.log"
    exit 0
fi
```

With my surprise the `if` condition is satisfied often but not always, as I can see from the log file.

Consider that for testing purposes I reproduced the problem with this code snippet, which means that the script lasts few milliseconds, no way that it lasts for a minute, to collide with the next cronjob call.

What am I missing? What can I try?

Comment: I'd start with a bit of simple debugging; when `$processes > 1`, also dump the full set of `ps` data (ie, not filtered through `grep` calls) to the log file; with the full set of `ps` data you'll likely find an issue with your logic and/or additional info about your shell script to explain why `$processes > 1`

Comment: also take a look at this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158694/7366100) which may apply in your case

Comment: I tried to dump every possible `ps` output to ensure that the logic works. The subprocess theory seems to me the more reasonable (and last) explanation and I think that in the end the culprit is `$(/bin/ps ux)` but how can I work around this?

Comment: I typically grab the current invocation's pid (`mypid=$$`); then filter out any `ps` results that include `$mypid`; this should filter out the current process (process = `$mypid`) plus any (short-lived) child processes (parent process = `$mypid`); something like `egrep -v " ${mypid} "` ... make note of the space before/after ${mypid} so that in the rare case we don't filter out 1234 when mypid=123

Comment: yes, I was working on a solution like that, something inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/25278679/1701296 which uses the `-w` option of `grep` to prevent the substring issue you mentioned. Some more tests but I think this is what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: yeah, there are probably a gazillion+1 ways to do it ... whatever works eh; I have some scripts that need to process multiple lines of `ps` output so I've developed the habit of using variables ($mypid, $pid, $ppid) for follow-on processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point that I was missing was that a shell can spawn subshells in other processes, that's why `ps` was finding more lines than expected.

With some help by @markp and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25278679/1701296) I rewrote the condition like this

```
processes=$(/bin/ps x -o pid,ppid,args | /bin/grep -vw $$ | /bin/grep -i "job.ksh TESTACTION" | /bin/grep -c "\/usr\/bin\/ksh")
if (( $processes > 0 )); then
     exit 0
fi
```

here the main points:

- The output of `ps` is formatted to include pid and parent pid information

  - I filter out the lines containing the current process'pid (contained into the special var `$$`)
  - this way I do not need to filter out `grep` executions
  - I had to change the check from `1` to `0` since also the current process was excluded from the `ps` results